# Resizing Android MediaPlayer in a SurfaceView

Tags: java, android, resize, media-player, surfaceview

I am building a video player for Android using a MediaPlayer in a SurfaceView. I added a button to resize the video but the code is not working. What's wrong with my code?

```
resize.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int w = mediaPlayer.getVideoWidth();
            if (w == 250) {
                metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
                getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
                android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams) videoSurface
                        .getLayoutParams();
                params.width = metrics.widthPixels;
                params.height = metrics.heightPixels;
                params.leftMargin = 0;
                videoSurface.setLayoutParams(params);
            } else {
                metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
                getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
                android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams) videoSurface
                        .getLayoutParams();
                params.width = (int) (250 * metrics.density);
                params.height = (int) (300 * metrics.density);
                params.leftMargin = 30;
                videoSurface.setLayoutParams(params);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried requesting a layout pass after setting the new layout params with either invalidate() or requestLayout()?

Comment: I tried it now but it's still now working.